# www.google.com returns HTTP 301

Tags: python, http, tcp, python-sockets

I'm looking at [this example](https://github.com/EONRaider/blackhat-python3/blob/master/chapter02/tcp-client.py) of making a simple HTTP request in Python using only the built in `socket` module:

```py
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"
target_port = 80


client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host, target_port))
client.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")
response = client.recv(4096) 
client.close()
print(response)
```

When I run this code, I get back a `301`:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

I'm confused by this because the "new location" looks identical to the URL I requested. Using `curl` or `wget` on the same URL (`www.google.com`) returns a `200`. I'm having a hard time understanding what is different. Are `curl`/`wget` getting the same `301` "behind the scenes" and just automatically requesting the 'new' resource? And if so how is that possible given that, as mentioned above, the 'new' location appears identical to the original?

Comment: Maybe, its stupid, but did you try to just:  target_host = http:/... (i cannot add full adres, since it will convert it into link here )

Comment: Add "www" to the domain in the Host header.

Comment: @Jakub This is a TCP request - target_host is supposed to be a hostname, not an URL.

Comment: Follow-up to my first comment: Note that `curl http://google.com` ( **without** www) also displays the same response (curl doesn't follow 301s by default, though wget does).

Comment: Ah, thanks so much @SuperStormer, adding `www` to that header does result in 200 for me (and conversely removing it from the `curl` call gives the same `301` as you mentioned)

Comment: Side note, an HTTP status 3XX redirect always redirects to the location send in the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) response header. Not what is in the body. (Though they are almost always the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused by this because the "new location" looks identical to the URL I requested

It doesn't. Your host header says that you are accessing `google.com`, i.e. without `www`:

> ```
> client.send(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n")
> ```

This gets redirected to `www.google.com`, i.e. with `www`:

> ```
> <A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
> ```

Comment: Thanks! My confusion stemmed from the fact that `www` *is included* in the `target_host` var which is used to set up the socket. But I suppose that is all happening at the TCP layer, and irrelevant to the server that responds to my HTTP request?

Comment: @Nick: the `target_host` is translated to an IP address using DNS and then a connection to this IP address is done. The peer has no idea about this, all it knows that somebody connected to its IP address and not which hostname was looked up to get the IP.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks @Steffen